# The caller does not have the necessary permissions for Azure Workflow Service

Tags: workflow, azure

I'm trying to get Azure Workflow Service running on SharePoint 2013.

When running the `Register-SPWorkflowService` powershell commandlet i get the following error:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService : The caller does not have the necessary
permissions required for this operation. Permissions granted: None. Required
permissions: ReadScope. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId:
221b6fef-bb5d-4455-a572-2c5a035e323a. NodeId: WIN-K19UNMVBQ40. Scope:
/SharePoint.
At line:1 char:1
+ Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://server" -WorkflowHostUri
"http://WIN- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...WorkflowService:
   RegisterSPWorkflowService) [Register-SPWorkflowService], UnauthorizedAcces
  sException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell
   .RegisterSPWorkflowService
```

Any pointers? I'm running the workflow service as the SPSetup account and I'm logged in as the SPSetup account. This account is also sysadmin on the SQL Server, should therefore have all permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard rumors that configuring this also requires the User Profile service application to be configured so that the OAuth/claims augmentation/etc. stuff can all be in place.  Unfortunately I haven't had the chance to confirm this yet.

Comment: Very interesting - will try to configure everything SharePoint related.

Comment: I don't know whether that was it, but after starting all possible Services via CA (including User profile service), the Powershell command did not result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with this is I forgot to put the account I was logged in as on the SharePoint server in the Workflow Manager Admin group. Added the account, logged out and back in (so I would get a new token), and it worked fine. I guess there is an admin group for a reason, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error but I got it working based on [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briangre/archive/2013/02/20/least-privilege-configuration-for-windows-azure-workflow-with-sharepoint-2013.aspx).

Just to help anyone else who may experience the same, here's an excerpt:

> You may receive one of the following errors and I’ve commented each
>   with the resolution I used:
>
> ERROR
>
> PROBLEM
>
> RESOLUTION
>
> Register-SPWorkflowService : The caller does not have the necessary
>   permissions required for this operation. Permissions granted: None.
>   Required permissions: WriteScope. HTTP headers received from the
>   server - ActivityId: 5e2b96c5-f971-48c9-b3fd-405c3616e1c7. NodeId:
>   SP2. Scope: /SharePoint. Client ActivityId :
>   8e592951-0027-40c6-b996-ba3dd194fdea.
>
> CONTOSO\svcSetupAcct is not a member of the workflow admin group,
>   CONTOSO\WFAdmins.
>
> Add CONTOSO\svcSetupAcct to CONTOSO\WFAdmins and re-run
>   Register-SPWorkflowService PowerShell cmdlet. You may need to logout
>   and log back in to acquire an updated security token.
>
> ```
> Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite url -WorkflowHostUri url –AllowOAuthHttp Register-SPWorkflowService : Cannot open database "WSS_Content_WFTest"
> ```
>
> requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'CONTOSO\svcsetupacct'.
>
> CONTOSO\svcSetupAcct has not been granted ShellAdmin access to the
>   WSS_Content_WFTest content database.
>
> Grant CONTOSO\svcSetupAcct shell admin access to the desired content
>   database using PowerShell similar to the following:  Add-SPShellAdmin
>   CONTOSO\svcSetupAcct –database (Get-SPContentDatabase
>   WSS_Content_WFTest)
>
> Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite url  -WorkflowHostUri url Register-SPWorkflowService : Failed to query the OAuth S2S metadata
>   endpoint at URI. Error
>   details: 'The metadata endpoint responded with an error. HTTP status
>   code: Forbidden.'. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId:
>   b5163152-3e31-4809-a532-5e20d1320027. NodeId: WF. Scope: /SharePoint.
>   Client ActivityId : b66b0ea4-d9a7-4d2d-8be8-3a0c58ab728c.
>
> Incorrect use of parameters
>
> Notice that the SharePoint site is non-SSL, but the parameter for
>   –AllowOAuthHttp was not specified. For a non-SSL SharePoint site, the
>   parameter –AllowOAuthHttp must be used.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, I had a bad mistake. I used Builtin(domain)\Administrators group for Workflow admin group and it was raise that error. I had to leave the farm and config again with new security group and add the domain user account for setup workflow, services and the user account that i logon for SharePoint configuration to new security group member list and it was solved

Answer (score -1):

In local installations, the account executing `Register-SPWorkflowService` must be able to write to the `-SPSite` site collection database (or even be owner - I used `GrantAccessToProcessIdentity` on the web app as I don't have management access to the SQL server) and member of the Workflow admin group `(Get-WFFarm).AdminGroup`.

Comment: You shouldn't do this.
Registering the workflow service you would do in a PowerShell instance running under farm credentials. The Farm administrator registers the WorkflowService with a site collection. The account running the workflow service shall not have access to the site collection database - that would defeat the whole purpose of having a decentralized workflow engine talking only via REST web services to SharePoint.